# Problem when string date to Date format in groovy:

Tags: groovy

I'm trying to compare a String with a date in it with the current date, but when I try to parse the string to date format it always give me an error.

the part of code that gives problem:

```
String data = "12-05-2020"
Date teste = Date.parse("dd-MM-yyy",data)
```

the error:

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static java.util.Date.parse() is applicable for argument types: (String, String) values: [dd-MM-yyy, 12-05-2020]
Possible solutions: parse(java.lang.String), wait(), clone(), grep(), any(), putAt(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object)
    at Script1.run(Script1.groovy:2)
```

It seems to be something very silly, so, if you could help me! Thanks a lot

Comment: Please add the error as text to the question instead of an image

Comment: I've managed to solved the problem, thank you all for the contributions!

Answer (score 10):

Since Groovy 2.5 (I think), the standard Java Date extensions have not been shipped with the groovy-all jar

If you *have* to use them, you'll need to include another dependency

```
org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-dateutil:«version»
```

(where `«version»` is the same as the version of Groovy you're using)

The reason for it's removal is that there are new (much better) Date Time classes in the `java.time` package...

So you can do the following in it's place:

```
import java.time.LocalDate

String data = "12-05-2020"
LocalDate teste = LocalDate.parse(data, "dd-MM-yyyy")
```

Without needing the extra library

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer, tu use that java.time.LocalDate, I dont need to concern with another dependency then?

Because I tried to run your solution, and It keeps with the same error

Thanks!

Comment: @19jmrs Are you using Java 8 or later? Did you include the `import` statement(s)? Also, I corrected the code example. Try it again.

Comment: Code example was fine and worked locally.  Rolled back.  @19jmrs the java version question is important

Comment: Yeah I did, it's actualy weird, I tried it on an online ide: https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/

Comment: Don’t you need four `y` characters rather than three?

Comment: @BasilBourque yes, that was just a mis click while writing there :)

Comment: I solved the problem by simply change of IDE o.O , thank you all for the answers! Sorry for the inconvinience

Comment: java.time JDK enhancements still require the extra library `groovy-datetime`

Answer (score 1):

## Argument data types mismatch

The error message told you exactly what is wrong:

> No signature of method: static java.util.Date.parse() is applicable for argument types: (String, String)

There is no such method on that class taking a pair of `String` objects.

Instead, you should be using:

- *java.time* classes only. Never use the terrible date-time classes such as `Date` and `Calendar`. Those legacy classes were entirely supplanted by *java.time* with the adoption of JSR 310 years ago.
- `DateTimeFormatter` to specify a custom formatting pattern.

Another problem: Your formatting pattern had only here `y` where it needed four. Also, in *java.time*, you can use `uuuu` rather than `yyyy` (though it makes no difference for contemporary dates).

In Java syntax (I do not know Groovy):

```
String input = "12-05-2020" ;
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd-MM-uuuu" ) ;
LocalDate teste = LocalDate.parse( input , f ) ;
```

Comment: This is Groovy There is a method String, String (I rolled back my correct solution below) http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/time/LocalDate.html#parse(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.String)

Comment: @tim_yates I did not know that about Groovy. My apologies.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem running a groovy script from eclipse 2022-03 (4.23.0)
with the groovy plugin.
I got around it by adding groovy-dateutil-.jar to the
run>Run Configurations...>Dependencies Tab>Classpath Entries